# Neo4j can we have graph visualisation in webadmin localhost:7474

Tags: neo4j

Can anyone tell.. Is it possible to install neo4j in ubuntu 12.04 with graph visualisation. I mean i have seen that in online cypher tutorial when we insert node than it shows graph of inserted node. if you want to get an idea what i am talking about please goto http://www.neo4j.org/console?id=cineasts and insert some node.You will see a graph for these node. Can we have the same UI in our local System also.

Comment: If you install neo4j and then start the server, you should be able to see the node visualization at http://localhost:7474
Are you unable to see it?

Comment: I am able to see Result in Table form                                                        neo4j-sh (?)$ start n=node(1000) return n;
==> +----------------------------------------------+
==> | n                                            |
==> +----------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[1000]{name:"West",message:"West added"} |
==> +----------------------------------------------+
==> 1 row,                             But what i want to say is that i want to know that can we see node connected by each other through straight line like graph. As we can see on online tutorials..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay you just need to click on the graph-like button on the data tab(far right). That toggles between tabular and graph view. [image]